# Не удается настроить $watch так, чтобы он реагировал на изменение данных

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть директива:

```
angular.module('analyticsMenu').directive('chartJs', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            type: '=',
            width: '=',
            height: '=',
            data: '=',
            options: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'analytics-menu/chart-js/chart-js.template.html',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {

            var newChart = function() {
                var ctx = $element.find('canvas')[0];
                var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: $scope.type,
                    data: $scope.data,
                    options: $scope.options
                });
            };

            var watchData = function() {
                return JSON.stringify($scope.data);
            };

            $scope.$watch('watchData', updateWhenDataChange, true);

            var updateWhenDataChange = function(newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log(123);
            }

            $timeout(newChart, 0);
        }
    }
}]);
```

При изменении атрибута data (а точнее, при изменении какого либо из параметров объектов которые я передаю директиве в качестве параметра), мне нужно перерисовывать график.

Сначала я просто попытался написать:

```
$scope.$watch('data', updateWhenDataChange, true);
```

Но это привело к ошибке:

> angular.js:13920 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: `$watch` выполняет переданную ему строку в контексте скопа для которого он вызывается, _watchData _ - не в скопе, соответственно `$scope.watchData` -никогда не меняется и всегда _undefiend_. Если добавишь рабочий пример, можно посмотреть что не так было с data

Comment: а зачем тебе еще и $timeout там внизу?

Comment: а еще возможен вариант, что в $watch подставляется значение _undefined_ а не функция, которая присваивается переменной позже

Comment: @Grundy, попробовал объявить функцию в `$scope`, к сожалению, все  равно не помогло.

Comment: @Grundy, по поводу `$timeout` - это временное решение использовалось до того, как я понял, что нужно использовать `$watch`. оно было необходимо для того, чтобы рисовать график после рендера страницы.

Comment: поэтому и нужен [mcve]

Comment: @Grundy, я смог выделить только необходимое. Пост обновлен.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44803/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пообщавшись в чате с @Grundy он мне подсказал, что нужно разбираться именно с этой проблемой (изначально я пытался ее "обойти"). Сегодня я все таки смог разобраться с ней.

Суть проблемы заключалась в том, что библиотека Chart.js писала свои "системные" данные в объекты, изменение состояния которых я проверял. Из за этого, постоянно вызывалась функция-обработчик изменения данных.

Как я решил проблему? Я создаю копию массива с данными БЕЗ свойства "_meta", в которое пишутся данные Chart.js. Проверяю изменение только этих данных. Вот код:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('analyticsMenu').directive('chartJs', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            type: '=',
            width: '=',
            height: '=',
            data: '=',
            options: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'analytics-menu/chart-js/chart-js.template.html',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {

            var canvas = $element.find('canvas')[0];
            var chart = null;

            var newChart = function() {
                if (chart === null) {
                    chart = new Chart(canvas, {
                        type: $scope.type,
                        data: $scope.data,
                        options: $scope.options
                    });
                } else {
                    chart.update();
                }
            };

            var without = function without(obj, keys) {
                if (obj === null || typeof obj !== 'object') {
                    return obj;
                }

                var temp = obj.constructor();
                for (var key in obj) {
                    if (key != '_meta') {
                        temp[key] = without(obj[key], keys);
                    }
                }

                return temp;
            };

            var watchComplexNode = function() {
                return without($scope.data, ['_meta']);
            };

            $scope.$watch(watchComplexNode, function () {
                newChart();
            }, true);

        }
    }
}]);
```

Так же рекомендую к прочтению вот эту [статью](https://tech.small-improvements.com/2014/06/11/deep-watching-circular-data-structures-in-angular/).

П.С. Еще раз спасибо за помощь @Grundy!

Answer (score -3):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
 .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
var watchData = function() {
    return JSON.stringify($scope.data);
};
 var updateWhenDataChange = function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(123);
}
$scope.$watch('watchData', updateWhenDataChange, true);

 }])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<main ng-app='app' ng-controller="MainController as main"></main>
```

Объяви сначала updateWhenDataChange, а потом его вызывай.

Comment: на самом деле не совсем так работает, так как _watchData_ в _$scope_  Не добавлена

Comment: добавил код. Работает без $scope

Comment: а теперь попробуй поменять значение в _$scope.data_

Comment: не очень понял. Поменял. Конечно от изменения $scope.data ничего не вызовется. $watch же на изменение watchData стоит

Comment: _watchData_ это функция, которая возвращает значение сериализованное значение _$scope.data_. Собственно ради чего автор вопроса и делал ее - отслеживать изменения этого поля. Приведенный код этого не выполняет, он отслеживает изменение _$scope.watchData_ которое всегда _undefined_

Comment: "Проблема, собственно, в том, что updateWhenDataChange никогда не вызывается, несмотря на то, что данные изменяются." - код выше решает это проблему.

Comment: _несмотря на то, что данные изменяются_ - вот эту проблему как раз не решает.

Comment: @alexander, да, действительно, функция вызывается 1 раз, но при изменении данных - нет.

Comment: конечно нет. Функция при изменении данных же не вызывается